# Itunesconnect : Issue with description language

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I've got a published application in itunes with two description languages English and French. 
Firstly the default language was set to French, recently I've changes the default description language from French to English and removed French description language.

But still it displays the French description language in French store. Should I submit new update for the application so it updates its description language in itunes for French store?

Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Comment: I think they use some kind of localization stuff for selecting language of a local, and translate language accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Apple just needs some time to apply those changes, actually it took for me a day.